# Mapping data.frame data to spatial grid data in R

Tags: r, grid, spatial

Suppose I have a data.frame `tem` representing 0.5° x 0.5° grid **global** surface temperature liking following：
(The original data is availabe at: https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/v4announcement.htm)

```
tem= as.data.frame(array(rnorm(360*720,mean =1, sd = 2),c(360,720)))
```

Each value in `tem` represents the average surface temperature for each grid.

I also have a `shp`file called `city.shp` representing a country's cities map liking the figure.It is a ploygon. And I read it by the following code:

```
city_map<-st_read("~city.shp", fid_column_name = 'FID')
city_map<-sf::st_transform(city_map,crs=4326)
```

I want to use the grid data to calculate the average temperature for each city. But I don't know how to achieve it.

I would really appreciate your help on this.
Many thanks
[image]

Comment: For some thoughts on [how to procede](https://tmieno2.github.io/R-as-GIS-for-Economists/extracting-values-from-raster-layers-for-vector-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by the following code:

```
library(terra)
tem_rast<-rast(nrows = 360, ncols = 720,
            xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax = 90,
            crs="+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m",vals=tem)
city_tem <-terra::extract(tem_rast, vect(city_map))
```